# Request dialog multiple friends

Tags: facebook-graph-api, request, fbjs

I saw this on "Sims Social" , wondering how they do that
  :
 [screenshot](http://cl.ly/013m2m2k091Q3k0P2Y2s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the standard app request dialog. You can read about it in the [developer documentation for dialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).